# What is the most efficient way to replace values in a data.table using a dictionary?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a pretty large data.table (1e7 by 50 columns). Apart from the key, the columns are logical. Here a mini-version.

```
library(data.table)
d.in <- data.table(
  id=c(rep(1:2,each=4)), 
  time=c(1:4,1:4),
  drugA=c(T,T,F,T, F,F,F,F),
  drugB=c(F,F,F,F, T,F,F,F)
  )
setkey(d.in, id,time)
```

which looks like this

```
id  time    drugA   drugB
1   1   TRUE    FALSE
1   2   TRUE    FALSE
1   3   FALSE   FALSE
1   4   TRUE    FALSE
2   1   FALSE   TRUE
2   2   FALSE   FALSE
2   3   FALSE   FALSE
2   4   FALSE   FALSE
```

I have a key-value 'dictionary'

```
kv <- c(drugA=1, drugB=2)
```

And I want to use this dictionary to replace values in the logical columns with the values in the 'dictionary'. The output should look like this.

```
id  time    drugA   drugB
1   1   1   NA
1   2   1   NA
1   3   NA  NA
1   4   1   NA
2   1   NA  2
2   2   NA  NA
2   3   NA  NA
2   4   NA  NA
```

What is the most efficient (quickest) way of doing this?

### Update

I have tried the solutions below, and can't find a big difference (although I am not sure that my approach to comparing is valid).

```
library(microbenchmark)
d.orig <- data.table(
  id=c(rep(1:2,each=1e7)), 
  time=c(1e7,1e7),
  drugA=sample(c(T,F), 2e7, replace=T),
  drugB=sample(c(T,F), 2e7, replace=T)
  )

# Solution 1
foo1 <- function() {
  d.in <- data.table::copy(d.orig)
  d.in[, names(kv) := lapply(names(kv), function(x) {
    gx <- get(x)
    replace(NA_real_[seq_along(gx)], gx, kv[x])
    })]
}

# Solution 2
dt_kv <- data.table(drug = c("drugA","drugB"), value = c(1,2))
foo2 <- function() {
  d.in <- data.table::copy(d.orig)
  d.in <- melt(d.in, id.vars = c("id", "time"))[ 
    dt_kv, on = c(variable = "drug"), nomatch = 0][
    value == FALSE, i.value := NA]

  dcast(d.in, formula = id + time ~ variable, value.var = "i.value")
}

# Solution 3
kDT = data.table(variable = names(kv), value = TRUE, v = unname(kv))
foo3 <- function() {
  d.in <- data.table::copy(d.orig)
  DT = melt(d.in, id=c("id","time"))
  DT[kDT, on=.(variable, value), v := i.v ]
  dcast(DT, formula = id + time ~ variable, value.var = 'v')
}
```

Which produces (albeit with a lot of variation still)

```
print(microbenchmark(foo1, times=1e4))
Unit: nanoseconds
 expr min lq    mean median uq   max neval
 foo1  33 50 85.8657     55 58 56717 10000

print(microbenchmark(foo2, times=1e4))
Unit: nanoseconds
 expr min lq    mean median uq   max neval
 foo2  29 48 70.8304     52 55 57644 10000

print(microbenchmark(foo3, times=1e4))
Unit: nanoseconds
 expr min lq    mean median uq   max neval
 foo3  30 36 61.1542     41 48 58015 10000
```

Comment: A common way would be to move your data to long format: `DT = melt(d.in, id=c("id","time")); kDT = data.table(variable = names(kv), value = TRUE, v = unname(kv)); DT[kDT, on=.(variable, value), v := i.v ]`. Generally, I think if you care a lot about speed or simple syntax, you'll want long-format data rather than wide.

Comment: @Frank - thanks: my original solution had been to melt but I was getting error messages saying the vector was too long. Will try your solution again though

Comment: Ok. It's standard to make a single microbenchmark call instead of a sequence, fyi. Also, I guess I'd argue that you should just keep your data in the DT form instead of d.in (and so would drop the melt to make it and the dcast to revert to wide in the benchmark, in which case it's probably much faster than the alternatives).

Comment: @Frank if you had a chance to transfer the code snippet you provided above to an answer, I could accept this as the best answer? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common way would start with moving your data to long format:

```
DT = melt(d.in, id=c("id","time"))
```

Then put the mapping in a table, similar to @SymbolixAU's answer:

```
kDT = data.table(variable = names(kv), value = TRUE, v = unname(kv))
```

Then use the mapping to do an update join, adding a new column by reference:

```
DT[kDT, on=.(variable, value), v := i.v ]
```

Generally, I think if you care a lot about speed or simple syntax, you'll want long-format data rather than wide in R, so I would skip the final `dcast` step (see @SymbolixAU's answer).

Comment: I guess the parameter in `melt` should be `id.vars` instead of `id` even though it works through partial matching of R...

Comment: @RYoda Yeah, that's the full name of the argument, I don't know that it *should* be typed in full here... after all, I didn't pass the arg name for the first arg in melt or in `[.data.table` either. Anyway, I also have some strong opinions about explicitly labeling args, like always writing `by=` instead of passing by position.

Comment: All I wanted to say is that `id` may be irritating for R beginners since they don't find this formal parameter name in the help of `melt` because it is named `id.vars`.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's the most efficient way, but you could do

```
d.in[, names(kv) := lapply(names(kv), function(x) {
        gx <- get(x)
        replace(NA_real_[seq_along(gx)], gx, kv[x])
    })]
```

Here we iterate over the names in `kv`, using `get` to retrieve the column values. Then we replace the relevant values of a newly created NA vector with our `kv` values, resulting in

> ```
>    id time drugA drugB
> 1:  1    1     1    NA
> 2:  1    2     1    NA
> 3:  1    3    NA    NA
> 4:  1    4     1    NA
> 5:  2    1    NA     2
> 6:  2    2    NA    NA
> 7:  2    3    NA    NA
> 8:  2    4    NA    NA
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `data.table` lookup dictionary, melt the original `d.in`, join, update, and reshape as required

```
dt_kv <- data.table(drug = c("drugA","drugB"),
                    value = c(1,2))

d.in <- melt(d.in, id.vars = c("id", "time"))[ 
  dt_kv, on = c(variable = "drug"), nomatch = 0][
    value == FALSE, i.value := NA]

dcast(d.in, formula = id + time ~ variable, value.var = "i.value")

#    id time drugA drugB
# 1:  1    1     1    NA
# 2:  1    2     1    NA
# 3:  1    3    NA    NA
# 4:  1    4     1    NA
# 5:  2    1    NA     2
# 6:  2    2    NA    NA
# 7:  2    3    NA    NA
# 8:  2    4    NA    NA
```

Comment: I'm your upvoter. Just guessing at the downvoter's motives. Fyi, the standard reference for not overthinking downvotes is this answer by Tim Post http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397 Gonna delete my earlier comment since you extended the answer so it doesn't require manually entering "drugA" and "drugB" three times.

Comment: @Frank - I'm definitely not worried about it, my question was merely to see if I had got something wrong :)

Comment: naturally, as Frank points out, if you can avoid `dcast`ing your data and work with it in long format it will naturally take away some time